# Arduino Serial.read() from xbee if statement

Tags: arduino, xbee

I am trying to finish a small project with a moisture sensor connected to a Fio V3.
I have also attach a Xbee S1 module to Fio's socket.

I have upload the following code to Fio:

```
int igrasia = 7;

void setup()

{
Serial1.begin(9600);
pinMode(igrasia, INPUT_PULLUP);

}

void loop(){
int sensorVal = digitalRead(igrasia);

if (sensorVal == HIGH) {
Serial1.println("0");     // Send OK to xbee

} 
else {
Serial1.println("1");     // Send NOT OK to xbee
}
delay(5000);
}
```

On my computer using the Xbee USB explorer I am receiving correct data on X-CTU every 5 seconds.
Zero (0) while the sensor is outside a glass of water and one (1) while the sensor is in the glass of water.

I want to read these bytes to an Arduino Uno with a LCD screen attached and an Xbee shield. For this reason I have uploaded to Uno the following code:

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x38,16,2); // set the LCD address to 0x20 for a 16 chars

void setup(){

Serial.begin(9600);

//configure pin2 as an input and enable the internal pull-up resistor
//  pinMode(8, INPUT_PULLUP);
pinMode(13, OUTPUT);
digitalWrite(13, LOW);
lcd.init(); // initialize the lcd

}

void loop(){

if(Serial.available())

 {

char getData = Serial.read();
if (getData == '1')
{
Serial.print(getData);
digitalWrite(13, HIGH);

lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor (0,0);        // go to start of 1st line
lcd.print("ATTENTION  !!!!"); 
lcd.setCursor (0,1);        // go to start of 1st line
lcd.print("WET environment"); 

} 
else {
Serial.print(getData);
digitalWrite(13, LOW);

lcd.clear();
lcd.setCursor (0,0);        // go to start of 1st line
lcd.print("dry environment"); 
lcd.setCursor (0,1);        // go to start of 1st line
lcd.print("all looks good!"); 

}


}

 }
```

It doesn't work properly :- (
I have correct functionality for 0 and while the sensor is outside the water. LCD monitor shows "dry environment".

But as soon as I place the sensor in the water, LCD is not working as required.
Even if I leave the sensor in the water the LCD still displays "dry environment".

I tried the sensor connected directly to Uno with the LCD attached and it works!
I suppose something is wrong with the serial.read() and/or my If / loop statement on UNO.

Any suggestions or advice?

Comment: What exactly is your serial readout? You have a few lines that print debugging type information there. Does any of that change when you put it in the water?

Comment: Alternatively (If above output is always the same), what code did you use when you connected directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you transmit the data, you're sending it as a `String` `"1"`, `"0"`.

On the receiver, you're testing for characters `'1'`, `'0'`. `String`s are terminated with a null character (`/u0000`), whereas characters are not. Therefore the condition is always failed. You could try transmitting and testing characters only.

Comment: replaced 0/1 with a/b and it works. However is not working with an IF else statement. I tried 2 IFs and it works great! Very impressed with the level of your expertise!